# rails pass instance variable to layout or local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have a navigation bar (in fact two) and I use a before action in some controllers to fill it's dynamic data (the second bar may not exist in some), I've seen a lot of complains about not passing a lot of instance variables to views, and all of them suggested passing locals in render. I've been wondering using a instance variable to generate these stuff in the main layout is a good idea or not, and if it's not, how should I do this, render seems to overwrite the default view and I use the data in the main layout only

Answer (score 1):

I not sure that I understand well your question. But for some of my menus I use something like that in my layouts:

```
<%= yield(:menu_top) %>
```

and I use

```
content_for :menu_top
```

to generate content in this area.

For exemple:

```
<%= content_for :menu_top do %>
  <li>my specific content or var</li>
<% end %>
```

Here is the rails guide for content_for: [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)

Comment: I did that too, but this method takes so much time, you should insert those content depending on the page to every page that has navigation, and its hard to change, you must change them all! ty for answer ;)

Comment: Ok, maybe for more complex logic you should try whith an helper or with a decorator/presenter. Actually I'm not so familiar with them, I'll post here if I find some docs!

Comment: I asked one of my teachers, he said since its being used in the main layout it's not that bad and it's ok, but Im still looking forward to do this without instance variables! ty ;)